# MonoTorrent client can't Reach Max download and upload Speed

Tags: monotorrent

i am developing client and tracker to distribute files in LAN, Bandwidth is 1Gbps, but the client's download speed and upload speed can't reach max bandwidth. The max speed only can reach almost 10MB/s.

how can i get the max upload speed and max download speed.

Comment: @Alan do you have any idea?

Answer (score -1):

http://monotorrent.fr.yuku.com/topic/539/master/1/?page=1#.U3CHo5IweBY
I figured out why this happened. And this may be helpful. 
Thank duff

Comment: Please provide a description *here* of what you have found and use an 
appropriate code formatting..